# finding index of last occurrence in a string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the index of last occurrence of a particular character in a string.

eg: s = [1,2,3,4,2,4,5,4]

in the above string I need to find the index of '4' that was situated last in the string. could anyone help me out in this?

Thank you

Comment: That's a list of integers, not a string. Strings have a method `rfind` that does what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Get the length which tells how many items are in your list (8) and minus one because indices start at 0 (0-7)

```
s = [1,2,3,4,2,4,5,4]

f = len(s) - 1

print f
print s[f]
```